# How to obtain the derived class type from base when calling a method

Tags: c#, types

Ive searched the internet and didnt immediately see a solution, should be simple but I just cant figure it out.

I need to obtain the derived class Type within a method that only passes in the base class:

```
class Base 
{
}

class Derived1 : Base
{
}

class Derived2 : Base
{
}

void SomeMethod(Base obj)
{
    Type baseType = obj.GetType();
    Type derivedType = obj.????
}

void Main()
{
    Base d1 = new Derived1();
    Base d2 = new Derived2();

    SomeMethod(d1);
    SomeMethod(d2);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.GetType()` returns actual type of current object. It doesn't return base type. So if you do `SomeMethod(new Derived1())`, `obj.GetType()` will return `Derived1` (seems like that is what you want).

Comment: Yes, sorry, i updated the example to reflect more of whats happening.  The derived classes are cast to Base on instantiation

Comment: @Tizz please read my answer carefully, GetType returns type of object. Casting reference type object doesn't change the type.

Comment: @Tizz As Andrey points out, GetType() returns the most derived type. You want `GetType().BaseType` to get the base type, and just `GetType()` for the derived type. `Type baseType = obj.GetType().BaseType;`, `Type derivedType = obj.GetType();`

Comment: This simple example is [obviously] not what my real life scenario is. This is why I didnt understand why GetType() wasnt working properly. I guess I have some digging to do in my code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you want something like this:

```
 using System.Reflection;
 ...

 void SomeMethod(Base obj) { 
   // Declared type, "Base" - since "Base obj" is declared in the method
   Type baseType = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
   // Actual type, "Derived1", "Derived2" - actually passed as parameter
   Type derivedType = obj.GetType();
   ...
 }
```